# how to detect if a domain is redirected to your website

Tags: php, redirect, dns, referer

I searched the internet (Google), and I searched on here also but can't seem to find an answer to my question.

Is there a way to tell if a request was redirected to my website?

For example there is website A:
subdomain.WebSiteA.com

Where it is set up to redirect to website B (my website):
www.WebSiteB.com

Is there a way that WebSiteB can determine that it is coming from subdomain.WebSiteB.com?

I can't find the answer online. I probably am not searching properly.

Also, I am using PHP as my environment language.

Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: Ooops sorry, mistake above. I meant to say:

Comment: Ooops again sorry. I meant to say "Is there a way that WebSiteB can determine that it is coming from subdomain.WebSiteA.com".

Answer (score 0):

If correctly understood your question , you can check **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']** , something like :

```
 if (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "subdomain.WebSiteA.com")){
   //redirected from subdomain.WebSiteA.com
}
```

Comment: I read that HTTP_REFERER might be blank at times though and you can't rely on that.